# Import package error with unmanaged dependencies in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt Scala project, that requires dependencies I am adding as unmanaged dependencies by adding the jars in `lib` folder of my project root directory.
I can see these jars when checking the unmanagedClasspath through command `show unmanagedClasspath`. However, when I try to compile my project, I get the errors: `object X is not a member of package Y` and `not found: type Z` .

I have verified that the dependency jars (that I added to the `lib` folder) have the classes in the expected hierarchy. I've tried searching for solutions online but am coming up empty. What am I missing?